# CPU Processing for high traffic site using .php extension

Tags: php

I have a high traffic site that uses .php includes for the header/footer. The pages themselves use the .php extension for legacy reasons.

Because the site has grown, it is consuming large amounts of CPU resources. My question is if I remove the .php includes (replace with static html), but leave the pages with the .php extension will this help reduce the processing or does the parser still work on a static page with .php extension?

I could also redirect the .php pages to .html, but I'm assuming that takes CPU resources as well.

Comment: First thing what is code in your header file ?

Comment: HTML files don't have to be passed and are served directly by the webserver. If you include header/footer through PHP it *will* have to go through the PHP parser, whether it's PHP files you include or not. This is **most likely** not your bottleneck. It's what you do in those imported files that is the bottleneck (DB/cURL/etc.).

Comment: How many cores is this server? What is the HDDs' speed? There is no reason you can't use static HTML. Do the header and footer files actually do anything besides `echo`? You can check out the [memcache module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and see if that can be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP will keep parsing the files if you use include. I can't seem to find any information about it though. What you can do is use the following function (1) `echo file_get_contents("file.html")`, this will not parse the files but just get the content and send it to the user. You will have to test yourself to see if it's faster.

Another thing you can try is enabling OPCache (> PHP 5.5) or APC (< PHP5.5). This should lower your cpu usage.

(1) https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php